# phpmyadmin exports html not sql

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin 4.4.7 and have previously exported MySql tables fine into .sql format.  However, it is now exporting in html format even though I select .sql format with either Quick or Advanced method.

Any thoughts/suggestions much appreciated.

Thank you.

Lyle

Comment: If you open the resulting .html file in a text editor, does it look like HTML or SQL?

Comment: Sometimes when exporting I see HTML followed by an error message at the end.

Answer (score 13):

Phpmyadmin does not export properly when the database is very large (more than 300 tables in my case).

I added the following inside php.ini at the end of the "Resource Limits" section:

```
max_input_vars = 5000;
```

now it works. More info [here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/235573-max-input-vars-1000-solved/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You can create a view for the result, then export data from that view.
It worked for me.

Comment: How to create a view of the results?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change PHP ini settings, then you may try to use adminer, a single PHP file that is a lightweight MySQL admin interface that let's you export as gzip too https://www.adminer.org/#download